# Maven wsdl import. How to use the generated files?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wsdl

i have a problem and I'm not able to solve or understand the hole workflow behind this process.

I use eclipse with maven.
This is my simple test pom.xml

```
...
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
              <version>2.2.8</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <build>
              <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <xdebug>true</xdebug>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <keep>true</keep>
                                <packageName>abc.model</packageName>
                                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport/</sourceDestDir>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin> 
              </plugins>
            </build>
...
```

The **jaxws-maven-plugin** generate the files in the **sourceDestDir**. The **build-helper-maven-plugin** add the files during the maven install process the to the correct folder and also into the resulting jar file. So far so good. 
But I'm not able to use the generated files/classes in eclipse. So in eclipse maven does not recognize the files as source or does not but this in the source path. Did I make an mistake or did I miss something?

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**
I observer a strange behavior. Same test project same pom file. If I import this existing Maven Project in eclipse it works like expected. I can directly use the generated files as source.

But if I delete this source folder, I'm still not able to restore this with maven.

Comment: add a generated-sources/wsimport/ folder to the project if it does not exist (you might need to refresh project with F5 after maven build) and make it a source folder: right mouse click -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's possible to define manually the generated file folder as source, but this is not what I'm looking for. I thought the plugin **build-helper-maven-plugin** define the folder automatically as source, but it does not. Did i misunderstood the functionality of this plugin or did I use it false?

Comment: You have correct pom configuration. `Maven Build Process` from within Eclipse does not change `.project` file, which describes Eclipse Project configuration and thus, after maven build you will not get new source-folder in Eclipse - you must make it manually. **build-helper-maven-plugin** define the folder as source folder and this is why you will get later no compile errors from within maven build. But this folder is not automatically visible to Eclipse. There is a chance to get it working properly automatically, but I think you need to extend maven plugin for it.

Comment: Seems that I have to do it manually. Nevertheless thanks for your detail answer.